# Is $[x, x)$ an invalid interval for *all* real values of $x$?

Tags: notation, real-numbers, interval-arithmetic

I'm writing some software at work and I believe it isn't a valid interval because it seems contradictory. To me, it reads as both an inclusion and exclusion of $x$ which seems like it would nonsense in all possible cases -- not even the empty interval would satisfy both criteria.

I wanted to ask here because I don't necessarily know enough to say for sure that this interval should be considered invalid. Rather than pulling such a statement out of relatively nowhere and asserting it in code for others, I'd like to hear from those who know more about it.

Comment: It would be the interval $\{w: x \leq w < x\}$ which is the empty set. Whether this notation is allowed may depend on the source giving the definition, but for coding purposes it's probably safe to raise an error in that case.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints)

Comment: It is important to realize the difference between: "the empty set" and "contradictory".

Comment: Well, $x = x$ for all real values of $x$ so $[x,x)$ must be interpreted as $\{y\in\mathbb R| x \le y < x\} = \{y \in \mathbb R| x\le y$ and $y < x\}=\{y\in \mathbb R| y\ge x$ and $y <x\}$ and by trichotomy of order there are on suchh $y$ so $[x,x) = \emptyset$.  To me that is never a valid interval but you book might vary as to whether that is legitimate notation and satisifies as an "interval" ... But there is no question that it is good/bad for all values and it is *not* the case that there are some values of $x$ where it is acceptable and some where it is not. It is *always* the empty set.

Comment: I think it would be fine to treat this as a valid object (but the emptyset): presumably the way something like this would arise in whatever programming task you're doing is as a *constraint* - "we want some $x$ which is $\ge y$ but $<z$" - and the emptiness of this set would reflect the nonexistence of an object satisfying that constraint, which is useful information. Now the question is whether it's more useful to display that information as an *error message* or not; I think not, since unsatisfiability of constraints is a meaningful (if unfortunate) situation.

Comment: " not even the empty interval would satisfy both criteria." It will vacuously hold.  To say "the set of all $y$ so that $5 \le y <5$" does *NOT* imply $5 < 5$.  To say the "ther is a  $y$ so that $5\le y < 5$ is not empty" *does* imply $5< 5$ but talking about "the set of all $y$ so that $5 \le y <5$" does not contradict anything if we conclude the set is empty.

Comment: Remember for elements in the empty set (of which there are none) all statements are true.  The statemet "$x$ is green" and "$x$ is not green" can not hold for any element of any non-empty set.  But on the empty set they *both* hold for ***all*** elements.  Vacuously.  So yes,  For all elements of the empty intervals, it is indeed true that every element of the empty interval that it is both greater or equal to $x$ and less than $x$.  Not only that, it is true for every element of the empty interval *and* for every real $x$.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it $\emptyset$, consistently with the notation $[a,b)=\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, a\le x\land x<b\}$. This is an interval because it is true that $$\forall x\in\emptyset,\forall y\in\emptyset,\forall z\in\Bbb R,(x<z<y\rightarrow z\in\emptyset)$$

Answer (score 0):

> To me, it reads as both an inclusion and exclusion of x which seems like it would nonsense in all possible cases -- **not even the empty interval** would satisfy both criteria.

Oh!  I see what you are asking.  It took me a few readings to get your concern.

The definition of $[x, y)$ is $\{w\in \mathbb R| x \le w < y\}$.  By that definition $[x,x) = \{w\in \mathbb R|x\le w < x\} = \emptyset$.  There is no problem with that.

But I think you are assuming the following propositions:

Proposition 1:  $x\in [x,y)$.

Proposition 2: $y\not \in [x,y)$

If so, then we can't have $[x,x)=\emptyset$ as that would imply $x \in \emptyset$.  But we can't have $[x,x)$ be *any* set as we need $x \in [x,x)$ and $x \not \in [x,x)$ and that's impossible.

....

But..... proposition 1: is not true.  It just isn't.

.....

By definiton:   $[x,y)=\{w|x\le w < y\}$.  This  is non-empty if $y > x$ (and in this case $x\in \color{blue}{[x,y)}$ because $\color{blue}{x \le} x\color{blue}{< y}$) and $[x,y)$ is empty if $y \le x$ (and in these cases $x\not \in \color{blue}{[x,}\color{red}{y)}$ because $\color{blue}{x \le} x \color{red}{\not < y}$.... and because.... it's empty... we *just* said that....).

So a proper stating of Prop 1 would be:

Prop 1':  If $[x,y)$ is non-empty, then $x\in[x,y)$. Furthermore $[x,y)$ is non-empty if and only if $y >x$.

And it this case $[x,x) = \emptyset$.

And $\emptyset=[x,x)$ satisfies both Prop 1' and Prop 2. Prop 1': If $[x,x)$ were non-empty the $x$ would be in it, but $[x,x)$ *is* empty and $x$ *isn't* in it.  Prop 2:  $x \not\in [x,x)=\emptyset$.